# Counting posts in category and auto removing from category

Tags: php, wordpress, function

my posts are listed in 2 categories. (featured, news).
iam trying to count posts in 'featured' category, and if its more than 5 i want it to remove 6,7,8, ... 
only keep latest 5.. 
so far iam able to count them using this code

```
$category = get_category(830);
$count = $category->category_count;

if( $count > 5 ) {
    // stuff
}
```

but inside the if statement how to get items 6,7,8... ?

i just want to remove category "featured" with category_id 830, and keep other category (news) if its listed in it.

i made this function , but i get error 500 when i use it.
can you help me?

```
$my_query = new WP_Query( 'category_name=featured' );
function countfeatures($my_query) {
$featurecount = 0;

    while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();
    $featurecount++;
    if ($featurecount > 5){  
    $pos = array_search( 'featured', $post_cats );
    unset( $post_cats[$pos] );
    wp_set_post_terms ($post_id, $post_cats, 'category');
    //wp_set_post_terms ($slide->ID, $post_cats, 'category');
    //do stuff 
    }
        endwhile;

    }
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'countfeatures');
```

Comment: use `limit` in a query?

Comment: its a function..
i just need to remove the article higher than 5  from the category

Answer (score 0):

Use Limit in query for 5 and Order by Primary key descending,so You will get top five latest record

Comment: in my code.. how can i catch the post number 6 ?
iam not able to catch it

Answer (score -1):

> Only orderby and order parameter needs to be added this will get you
>   newest 5 posts of featured category.

```
    $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'post_status'=> 'publish',
            'posts_per_page'=>5,
            'order'=>'DESC',
            'orderby'=>'ID',
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'featured',
                    'field'    => 'term_id',
                    'terms'    => array(830),
                    'operator' => 'IN',
                ),
            ),
        );
        $query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
} else {
    // no posts found
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Thank you, it seems you are not understanding me my friend.
iam able to get the posts of the category... but i want to remove the post (6) from category... not show only 5 from category.

like if you count 1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8   6+7+8 needs to be removed from category

(6+7+8) have categories (featured + news) remove them mean they should have only (news) as category.

Comment: Ok understood silly me :P ..
if($counter > 5){
wp_remove_object_terms( $post_id, 'featured', 'taxonomy' );
}

Comment: Stop posting multiple answers. If you need to add/delete/modify something, you can file an edit to your original post make the necessary changes